# No code completion in XML code within fully qualified tag

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

Why does code within a fully qualified tag lack auto-completion in Eclipse?

For example, within the following code (where the comment is) nothing I type is provided auto completion for member names / tag names.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView 
  android:id="@+id/gesturePage01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1.0">

  <!-- All code entered here lacks code completion -->

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Autocompletion works fine on my other code which is not embedded within a tag which is fully qualified...

Comment: It's just a bug... you could submit a bug report to the Android plugin developers.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed this issue and I hate it.

I just stumbled upon [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying)

Try:

```
<view
class="com.android.notepad.NoteEditor$MyEditText" 
id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:drawable/empty"
android:padding="10dip"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadingEdge="vertical" />
```

When I used this method, code completion worked a lot better.  It still only has the "View" class attributes visible though.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up for others reading this. This has now been [fixed](http://tools.android.com/recent/adt12bugfixroundup) in ADT 12.0:

> - Code completion inside a custom view layout has been improved